# Add data to a new line in UITextView every time button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I currently have a function that, when a button is pressed, takes a value that is determined from a UIStepper and adds it to a list of numbers. When I press the `Add Tip` button, it correctly displays the tip amount in the text view, but when I add a new value it replaces it rather than adding it underneath. 
Here is the function:

```
    @IBAction func addTipButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let tipDollarCent = dollar + cent
        sampleLog.text = "\(tipDollarCent)\n"
        totalLabel.text = tipDollarCent
    }
```

`sampleLog` is the Text View that needs to take a variable amount of lines of data, depending on how many time the user presses `addTipButton`

I am aware that my best course of action is probably to do an incremental loop, and I have tried implementing a separate `addNewLine` function, but `tipDollarCent` was out of scope and gave me an error.

I also initially tried adding `sampleLog.text = "\(tipDollarCent)\n" += "\(tipDollarCent)\n"` directly to the function.

I am hoping someone would be able to patiently and kindly explain to me what the best loop to use in this scenario would be, and how to properly implement it.

Here is a screenshot of my app so it is easier to see what I am trying to accomplish[image]

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, have you tried just to concatenate the `sampleLog.text` with the new string using the `+=` operator?

Comment: That was one of the first things I've tried, as such: `sampleLog.text = "\(tipDollarCent)\n" += "\(tipDollarCent)\n"`

I will add that to the original post for clarity

Comment: Do you mean `sampleLog.text += "\(tipDollarCent)\n"`? The line you gave isn't valid?

Comment: Also, clarifying, you want the `samepleLog` to grow with each new `tipDollarCent`, but the `totalLabel` will change for each button click. Is this correct?

Comment: That's where my problem lies. My apologies for the beginner mistake. Your implementation works, although I had to force unwrap `sampleLog.text!` 
Since there will always be a value given, I shouldn't have to worry about the optional, right?

Comment: @jacobbullon no worries. You can force unwrap it. The text property will never be nil

Comment: And I don't need to sampleLog to accumulate, simply display each value entered. I will be adding all of the values to each other using `totalLabel.text`, but I wanted to try to figure that out on my own based on what I learn here.

Comment: So `totalLabel` will accumulate?

Comment: Yes, so would I use the same += operator, except work with the data as a double rather than a string, so it is added together rather than concatenated?

Comment: `sampleLog.text! += "whatever"` will always add that string to the end of the textfield string if you would like to add text where the cursor it is located you can use `UIKeyInput` method `insertText` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614543-inserttext

Comment: It depends what you're doing with this new data that's a double now, being that `totalLabel.text` expects a string.

Comment: I think you should consider using multiple UITextFields instead of a single UITextView with multiple lines

Comment: I will be adding the doubles together so it can keep track of the total tip amount entered, then dividing them by the number of times the `add tip` button is pressed to display an average. I will add a screenshot to the original post so my intentions are more clear

Comment: Why do you need a UITextView? if the user doesn't need to edit it manually you can use a UILabel with multiple lines

Comment: Thank you both for your good advice and documentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the textView text to append the newly created string, you can use the compound-assign operator for addition `+=` to concatenate the what you previous had and grow it with a new string value.

```
var foo:String = "Foo"
let bar:String = "Bar"
foo += bar /* FooBar */ /* foo = foo + bar */
```

And for your comment on additions with doubles, the compound operator will also work with same-typed operands.

```
var pi:Double = 3.0
let fourteen:Double = 0.14
pi += fourteen /* 3.14 */ /* pi = pi + fourteen */
```

Comment: checking if textView text property is nil is pointless. Even if you assign nil to it before checking if it is nil it will return false

Comment: @LeoDabus Interesting, I'll take that part out.